# Output entities with relationships in json

Tags: laravel, laravel-3

I have a device entity which has one-to-many relationship with picture entity. Like one device has many pictures. How can I output in JSON all device properties plus array of pictures?

When I try:

```
dd(Device::find(1)->pictures);
```

I get array of laravel objects with some additional information. I tried to do it in some ways but didn't managed to get just an array of simple picture objects (or array of arrays)

Although this works:

```
foreach (Device::find(1)->pictures as $picture) {
    $data['pictures']['path'] = $picture->path;
}
dd($data['pictures']);
```

It seems weird to form array that way

Basically I need to output json with arrays of one-to-many objects, like pictures and some other. So I'll get something like:

```
["name": "myDevice", "price": "15", "pictures": [...], "another": [...]]
```

I am using laravel 3

Comment: Please specify if you're using Laravel 3 or 4, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Laravel 3? In that case this should do the trick:

```
return Response::eloquent(Device::with('pictures')->find(1));
```

If your are using `Response::eloquent` the content-type is also automatically set to application/json.

Edit: if you want only certain fields to return, you could use `Response::json(Device::with('pictures')->lists('name', 'id'));` to return an array just of that values already JSONified.

Comment: Yes, I'm using laravel 3. I can't right now test this, but what I need to create my own array to output without using ::eloquent method? I mean, not each field I'm returning is an entity field, it might be like "success":"true" + all these fields... anyways thanks, I'll try

Comment: $device = Device::with('pictures')->to_array() and then json it, works  very nice. The only question I got: if I want to display only some of fields of pictures, is it easy to do? Anyway, thanks! Nice site you have in your profile :)